# undefined is not a function (near '...'createRouter...') error when use MaterialTopTabNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, navigationbar

I want to use MaterialTopTabNavigator in my project but i get this error:

[image]

This is my code:

```
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import {Like, Home, Search, Media, Profile, Header} from './components/index';
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

And

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const MyTabs=()=>{


return(
    <NavigationContainer>

    <Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Like" component={Like} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={Search} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Media" component={Media} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
  </Tab.Navigator>

  </NavigationContainer>

)

}
```

I should say when i change type of navigation bar to `createBottomTabNavigator` everything works fine, Issue is just with `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`

How can i fix this?

Comment: Upgrade your dependencies

Comment: I did right now but issue is persisting with same error, The weird thing is ```createBottomTabNavigator``` works without any problem

Comment: If you get same error try deleting your yarn.lock/package-lock.json and reinstall. Then run npx react-native start --reset-cache or expo start -c

Comment: Thanks buddy, I would try